# Using Chart.js inside InfoBubble.js for Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) inside [InfoBubble.js](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/?compiled). You can see the work I have done so far here http://jsfiddle.net/qJZe5/1/. You can see the line chart is loading below the map (I included this for testing purposes). It works inside the InfoBubble in an odd way. For example, when you run the JSFiddle, click on the marker and then 'Launch', nothing happens. Close InfoBubble, and re-try and it works.

**How do I make it so the graph shows up when you first click 'Launch'?**

I think the following line is somehow misbehaving. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() { drawChart(); });
```

**Edit**: I also noticed that if I delete the code in HTML for loading the graph, nothing works.

My code:

```
function drawChart() {
    var randomScalingFactor = function () {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
    };
    var lineChartData = {
        labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Week 1",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
        }, {
            label: "Week 2",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
        }]
    };
    var options = {
        animation: true,
        scaleShowGridLines: true,
        scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
        scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
        bezierCurve: true,
        bezierCurveTension: 0.5,
        pointDot: true,
        pointDotRadius: 4,
        pointDotStrokeWidth: 2,
        pointHitDetectionRadius: 20,
        datasetStroke: true,
        datasetStrokeWidth: 2,
        datasetFill: true
    };
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, options);
}

function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: myLatlng
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
        '<a onclick="$(&quot;#graph&quot;).dialog();" href="#">Launch</a>' +
        '<div id="graph"><canvas id="canvas" height="250" width="250"></canvas></div>' +
        '</div>';

    var infowindow = new InfoBubble({
        content: contentString
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() { drawChart(); });
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work.  It generates this message: `Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nnnick/Chart.js/master/Chart.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Comment: @geocodezip Odd. It was working fine at my end. I have updated the JSFiddle. Uploaded Chart.min.js elsewhere. Please let me know if it is working now. Thank you.

Comment: @geocodezip I also just noticed that if I remove the chart from the HTML code, nothing works.

Comment: You have 2 elements with id="canvas", that is not legal.  If you remove the hardcoded one, you need to remove the call to drawChart that depends on it, or you will get a javascript error.

Comment: I removed it from HTML but nothing works now: http://jsfiddle.net/qJZe5/2/.

Comment: Seems like the 'domready' doesn't work.  If I [add a setTimeout to give the DOM time to render](http://jsfiddle.net/qJZe5/3/) I get the infowindow and the dialog (but no chart).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57881/discussion-between-kolor-and-geocodezip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the drawGraph function in the "create" method of the JQuery dialog:

```
'<a onclick="$(&quot;#graph&quot;).dialog({create: function( event, ui ) { drawChart(); }});" href="#">Launch</a>' +
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJZe5/5/)

[dialog create event documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-create)

Comment: Sweet. This works. Thank you. But when you click Launch to show the graph, then close the InfoBubble and load again, you have to click Launch twice to make it work. Something tells me this is an issue with InfoBubble.js.